# Type has no subscript members

Tags: swift

I use the [SwiftyJson](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON) library to help me parse json response.

This code:

```
Alamofire.request(req).validate().responseJSON { (response) in


    switch response.result{
    case .success(let dataJson):
        let json = JSON(dataJson)

for (key, subJson) in json.enumerated() {
                print("iterate")
                print(key)
                print(subJson)
                subJson["name"]
            }

        case .failure(let error):
            print(error)
        }
```

Does not work, and yields:

> subJson["name"] -  `Type '(String, JSON)' has no subscript members`

However, when I change it to:

```
 for (key, subJson):(String, JSON) in json {
                print("iterate")
                print(key)
                print(subJson)
                subJson["name"]
            }
```

It works. But why

```
for (key, subJson) in json.enumerated() {
                    print("iterate")
                    print(key)
                    print(subJson)
                    subJson["name"]
                }
```

does the above work?

Comment: So, it only works when you have an explicit type annotation, right?

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder look like so.

Comment: I also see you have dropped `.enumerated()` in the second code snippet. Is that on purpose? Try changing it in the other code as well, and see what you get

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking at wrong side the issue is not with explicit type `(String, JSON)`, when you specify the the explicit type `(String, JSON)` you have removed the `enumerated()` if you put the `enumerated()` also with it you will get error.

```
for (key, subJson):(String, JSON) in json.enumerated() {

}
```

> (offset: Int, element: (String, JSON))' is not convertible to '(String, JSON)

From Apple Documentation: [`enumerated()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/1687832-enumerated)

> Returns a sequence of pairs (n, x), where n represents a consecutive integer starting at zero, and x represents an element of the sequence.

Means when you use `enumerated()` Xcode will consider `key` as index and `subJson` as tuple of `(String, JSON)` so that is the reason you are getting that array. Now you actually don't need to use `enumerated` here as of when you use `for in` loop with `JSON` it will already give you `(String, JSON)` so use that one.

```
for (key, subJson) in json {
    print("iterate")
    print(key)
    print(subJson)
    subJson["name"]
}
```

Comment: "I also see you have dropped `.enumerated()` in the second code snippet. Is that on purpose? Try changing it in the other code as well, and see what you get" - That seemed to apply... Couldn't really test it and thus I haven't added an answer.

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder yes i did it on purpose because when i remove it error disappear.